# How to add custom view as navigation bar left item with whole view is able to tap

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar

I didn't get tap on whole view after added the view as a left barbutton item of the navigation bar. The following be the implementation which I followed. The location icon, text "Dubai" and down arrow are placed in a view. Then add a button as a subview on top of all view. After that the whole view set as the left bar button item of the navigation bar. But the click of button is not worked.

[image]